# Incorrect year after unix time convert

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have the following code. I'm trying to convert the unixtime to date format and i get a wrong year (`Sun Mar 24 48447 18:26:27`) instead of 2016.

```
//obj.uploadDate = 1466679630387
var uploadDate = new Date(obj.uploadDate * 1000);
```

How can this issue be fixed?

Comment: Don't multiply by 1000.

Comment: Yeah, it's already in milliseconds.

Comment: That's what i tried at the beginning but i got `Invalid Date {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `obj.fileName` the timestamp is already in JavaScript timestamp (milliseconds) you don't need to multiply by 1000, just use

```
// obj.uploadDate = 1466679630387
var uploadDate = new Date(obj.uploadDate);
```

Comment: I got `Invalid Date {}`.

Comment: If obj.uploadDate is numeric and its value is 1466679630387 and you pass the value to the Date constructor should be Thu Jun 23 2016 07:00:30 GMT-0400 (AST). it's look that you are using a string '1466679630387';

Comment: Thanks! I converted it to number and now it's work great!